# if $\phi_{X}^{(n)}(0) = \phi_{Y}^{(n)}(0) \ \forall n\in \{0\}\cup \mathbb{N}$. Are $X,Y$ identically distributed?

Tags: probability-theory

I have two random variables $X,Y$ for which I wish to provet that they are identically distributed. I have managed to show that the characteristic functions $\phi_X, \ \phi_Y$, and all of their derivatives, are equal for $t=0$. Can I draw the conclusion that $\phi_X = \phi_Y$ $\forall t$ and hence $X,Y$ are identically distributed?

Comment: The answer is negative, unless $\phi_X$ and $\phi_Y$ are analytic.